# Why I canot get the same result using the getDay() method and the getUTCDay() method on the Javascript Date object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, date, utc

Today we are Monday it's 00:51 am I am from Quebec city and therefor I am in GMT-0500 (UTC−05:00)

I dont know why the code below gives me 2 different results :

```
const weekday = Array('sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 
                      'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday');

console.log('getDay() =', weekday[new Date('2019-02-18').getDay()]); 
  // getDay() = sunday

console.log('getUTCDay() =', weekday[new Date('2019-02-18').getUTCDay()]); 
  // getUTCDay() = monday
```

On the MDN web site they say The getDay() method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday.

And they say exactly the same for The getUTCDay() method returns the day of the week in the specified date according to universal time, where 0 represents Sunday.

The only difference is one is according to local time and the other one is according to universal time...

I am not sure what I should verify to understand the difference I tried both [in Node.js (Typescript)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JSWT.png) and in the console [Chrome DevTools (Javascript)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfD2u.png)

In my computer settings the first day of a week is Sunday...

Comment: it is giving monday as result on both log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new Date(`*`string`*`)` uses `Date.parse()` to parse the date.

From the `Date.parse()` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format):

> When the time zone offset is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as local time.

Therefore, the date created by `new Date('2019-02-18')` will be exactly midnight on Feb 18, 2019 in **UTC time**.

If you are in a timezone with a negative offset then that date will actually be Sunday in local time (Quebec City is at GMT-0500 so that date is 2019-02-17:19:00:00 local time).

So if you are in a time zone with a negative offset then `.getDay()` is correctly returning `0` for Sunday, while `.getUTCDay()` is correctly returning `1` for Monday.

Comment: Though the general advice is "*do not use the built–in parser*". ECMAScript is quirky in that date–only forms of ISO 8601 formatted dates are treated as UTC, whereas everywhere else they are treated as local (including HTML forms).